# How to load JSON image urls in CollectionView faster in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, uicollectionview, uiimageview

I have collection view with image and label.. i am able to load images and label values very slowly in collection view i mean collection view take so much time to download json img urls.. but i need faster download from json to collection view... and i am not getting fast 10 images same.. i dont know why its happening like this.. any one please help me in download json img url in collection view with faster download.

here is my code:

```
 import UIKit
struct JsonData {
var iconHome: String?
var typeName: String?
init(icon: String, tpe: String) {
    self.iconHome = icon
    self.typeName = tpe
}
}

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

var itemsArray = [JsonData]()
var idArray = [Int]()
var homSe = [JsonDataHome]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    homeServiceCall()
    //Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return itemsArray.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! HomeCollectionViewCell

    let aData = itemsArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.paymentLabel.text = aData.typeName

    if let url = NSURL(string: aData.iconHome ?? "") {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOf: url as URL) {
            cell.paymentImage.image = UIImage(data: data as Data)
        }
    }
    return cell
}

//MARK:- Service-call
func homeServiceCall(){

    let urlStr = "https://dev.com/webservices"
    let url = URL(string: urlStr)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

        guard let respData = data else {
            return
        }
        guard error == nil else {
            print("error")
            return
        }
        do{
            let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: respData, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: Any]
            //print("the home json is \(jsonObj)")
            let financerArray = jsonObj["financer"] as! [[String: Any]]
            for financer in financerArray {

                let id = financer["id"] as? Int
                let pic = financer["icon"] as? String
                let typeName = financer["tpe"] as! String
                self.idArray.append(id ?? 1)

                self.itemsArray.append(JsonData(icon: pic ?? "", tpe: typeName))
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        catch {
            print("catch error")
        }
    }).resume()
}
}
```

here i need fast download json images in collection view .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First** there is no thing faster than what's inside `homeServiceCall()` it depends on your internet connection

**Second** this line

`if let data = NSData(contentsOf: url as URL) {`

blocks the main thread and causes re-download of same image multiple times when scrolling ,  use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage) to get benefits of single asynchronous download and caching

```
import SDWebImage 
cell.paymentImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:aData.iconHome ?? ""), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```

Comment: thank you, i have installed pod 'SDWebImage' cocopods, just one doubt i am getting all image urls from json but in collection view i am not getting first 10 and remaining are coming why.. have any idea

Comment: make sure url is not nil